# Chunked transfer decoder, code snippet for C

Tags: c, decode, chunked-encoding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Decoding chunked HTTP with Actionscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287920/decoding-chunked-http-with-actionscript)

I'm making a http server that merely allows access to my folder, download the files in it and also uploading to a folder. So far I have already done most of it, the only thing left is the uploading of the files. Whenever I receive files from a client, they send chunked datas.

Which I don't understand to decode. All I need is a function that decodes the data that I receive on my socket. Or even a way so that I could unallow the browser to send a Chunked transfers.

Answer (score 0):

Chunked transfer is part of the HTTP/1.1 spec.  If your server only responded with HTTP/1.0 responses, I would expect the client to upload the data without using chunks.

Comment: Hmm, well im not sure. I always respond to the client its 1.0 but for what ever reason, each time the client uses the upload form I supply to them. It always gives me a chunk, the header also says HTTP/1.1